# Convert latitude/longitude to three dimensional space

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, latitude-longitude, 3d

I am working to convert longitude to latitude to three-dimensional space in the form of x,y,z.

```
def transform(lat, lon):
    x = np.cos(np.radians(lat)) * np.cos(np.radians(lon))
    y = np.cos(np.radians(lat)) * np.sin(np.radians(lon))
    z = np.sin(np.radians(lat))
    return x,y,z
```

Also, I need to make a function that reverses the operation. ie. convert back x,y,z into lon/lat.

```
lat = np.degrees(np.arcsin(z))
```

This gives the value of latitude by inversing equation `z = np.sin(np.radians(lat))`. but I couldn't recover the longitude values. I tried solving the equations but it's returning a different value from what I expected.

I know taking the inverse of sine returns multiple values, I tried multiple values but could not get anyone close to the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution:

```
def inverse_transform(x,y,z):
  lat = np.degrees(np.arcsin(z))
  lon_1 = np.degrees(np.arcsin(y / np.cos(np.radians(lat))))
  lon_2 = np.degrees(np.arcsin(x / np.cos(np.radians(lat))))

  lon = 0

  if(lon_1 > 0 and lon_2 > 0): # for 0 to +90
    lon = lon_1
    
  elif(lon_1 < 0 and lon_2 > 0): # for -90 to 0
    lon = lon_1 

  elif(lon_1 < 0 and lon_2 < 0): # for -180 to -90
    lon = -lon_1 - 180    

  elif(lon_1 > 0 and lon_2 < 0): # for -180 to -90
    lon = 180 - lon_1 

  return lat,lon
```